# Low Battery Notification for All Devices

Tags: iphone, battery, airpods

Is it possible to get "low battery" notifications for all the devices that are connected to my iPhone? I have AirPods and Apple Watch connected to it.

I know I can see the battery levels in the "Battery widget", but I like to receive notifications for them.

Comment: Might have to look for a 3rd party app for that.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson Do you know any?

Comment: Nope, but I can look for you